# MySQL trigger to update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've been working for quite a while with MySQL and lately came across a rather unusual problem with triggers.

I have a table like on picture.

[image]

As it can be seen, total_per_unit column just simply multiplies quantity and price of each product. In turn, total_per_ticket sums up those total_per_unit by purchase_id.
Then I create a trigger to update total_per_unit when quantity or unit_price are altered.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tot_per_un_bef_upd
BEFORE UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.total_per_unit = NEW.quantity * NEW.unit_price;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And when using a simple update:

```
UPDATE products
SET quantity = 10
WHERE id = 1;
```

it all works perfectly.

Now I'm facing the problem of updating total_per_ticket column... If I use trigger with `BEFORE`, the update is made based on the values in only one row. When using `AFTER` and `UPDATE` like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tot_per_un_bef_upd
AFTER UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE products
    SET total_per_unit = (SUM(total_per_unit) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id));
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

it doesn't worke, because a trigger with update can't be run when updating a value in table.

I even tried to trick it and used a stored procedure put inside the trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE upd_tot_tick()
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    SELECT id, SUM(un_pr*quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number) AS new_tot
    FROM test
    );

    UPDATE test t1
    JOIN tmp USING (id)
    SET t1.total_price_per_ticket = tmp.new_tot
    
END//

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tot_per_un_bef_upd
AFTER UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL upd_tot_tick();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

but useless...

Maybe somebody has encountered a similar problem before, I would appreciate any clues or suggestions how to accomplish this task (preferably using trigger or any other type of automatic update).

Comment: Maybe it will be better to create view instead of try to implement some magic with triggers? `create or replace view products_w as select id, quantity, unit_price, 
 quantity*unit_price as total_per_unit  from products;`

Comment: Also see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database